# Blockquotes and code blocks are not working properly in Pagedown

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am trying to use [Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) to convert some markdown into HTML.

I have a div with some markdown in it

```
<div id="text"> 
>  This is supposed to be a blockquote

    1 < 2
</div>
```

and I'm converting it to HTML with this code

```
$(function () {
  var sanitizer = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
  var text = $("#text").html();
  $("#text").html(sanitizer.makeHtml(text));
});
```

There is no blockquote, and the left angle bracket (`<`) in the code block is converted to `&lt;`.

You can observe my problem [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGNsM/2/).

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: Try using `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.text()` when extracting the text from the DOM. `.html()` will encode some symbols as entities.

http://jsfiddle.net/fGNsM/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var $text = $('#text'),
      convert = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter().makeHtml,
      result = convert($text.text());
  $text.html(result);
});
```